# The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.14.props" was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was editing a .vcxproj file while converting it from VS2012 to VS2017 and now the project doesn't load in VS2017. Here is the error message:

Unable to read the project file "Manager.vcxproj".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.props(27,3): The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Redirect.14.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

I think the error is related to these lines in the project file:

```
 <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
```

However, other projects in my solution use the same import paths and still load correctly. Are these lines what is causing the issue? If so, what is the correct path and why do my other projects work when this path is used?

Comment: You do not have the original version (version control)? You could create a new project and compare the .vcxproj file.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenHeier the code in main which is built for VS2017 also has this issue , but I found a shelveset from a couple years ago when the team had tried to port the project to VS2015 that worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error can be fixed by adding the below code segment after the "Globals" PropertyGroup closes:

`<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />`

While the project can load in VS2012 without this line, it will not in VS2017.